# The p of ps - grid puzzle

Tags: knowledge, grid-deduction

Please fill in all boxes with letters. (And what is the p of ps?)

[image: P of ps]

Comment: is this related to ROT13(Gragnv fubj, crepunapr?)

Comment: @someoneinexistence This requires no special knowledge (like that) to make significant progress, at which point any knowledge needed is easily found.

Comment: it just looked like it to me… I’ve been doing lots of Nikoli.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'p of ps' is:

> **EUROPE**

And the image should be completed like this:

> [image: Image completed with letters]

Allow me to talk you through my thought process step-by-step...

**Step 1:**

The first thing of note here was that there are...

> ...exactly 26 boxes in the graphic in the top-right of the image. Since we are required to replace all symbols and spaces with letters it's not a big leap to suppose that we are intended to fill each of these 26 boxes with a different letter of the English alphabet.

How to do this though? My next thought was that the clusters of boxes might represent...

> ...**words spelled with these letters**, with the number of times that letter appeared being **proportional to the size of its box outline**.
>
>  Since the cluster second in from the left only had two unknowns I focussed on that word first, trying to work out what word might be spelled from the letter jumble {IILT##@}. I soon hit upon **ITALIAN** as a possibility. If we then substituted #=A and @=N in all other parts of the image, I then realised that the top letter jumble {AAACDINNNS.} had a related answer: **SCANDINAVIAN**! It seemed I was on to something...
>
>  [image: Step 1]

**Step 2:**

I now started to think about the theme - what was it exactly? Clearly it would be something related to...

> ...geography, culture or languages, and I turned my attention to the bottom-right {ACIMN$*} jumble. For a long while I got sucked into the language route, considering this to be either ROMANIC or ARMENIC...

Then another realisation struck me. What if the central cluster was supposed to indicate...

> ...**EUROPE**? This would fit with whatever theme I was currently uncovering. For this to be the case, we would have to have *=E (ruling out ROMANIC) and $=R. ARMENIC it was, then... (At least for now...)
>
>  [image: Step 2]

**Step 3:**

At this point I realised the error of my ways...

> Looking at the bottom-left jumble {AEIINR~} and the one two to its right {AALN^~} I spotted that if ~=B and ^=K we could spell **IBERIAN** and **BALKAN** - these weren't language-related at all; they were **European peninsulas**! This meant my 'ARMENIC' was actually **CRIMEAN**, and I had inadvertently pinpointed E and R whilst having completely misidentified what they represented!
>
>  [image: Step 3]

**Step 4:**

Now armed with the knowledge of the theme, I was able to resolve the final jumble:

> {ADLNT?.} was **JUTLAND**, with ?=U since this also had to appear as a letter in 'E**U**ROPE'.
>
>  [image: Step 4a]

But how to disambiguate the final two? This was where the top-right grid came in again...

> Noting that so far all of the letters were appearing within their '0', '1', '2', '3' and '4' categories in alphabetical order from left to right, I reasoned that the arrow beneath it must be suggesting this ordering. But without knowing what these numbered categories actually *are*, we're in a bit of a pickle...

This was when I turned my attention fully to working out what this grid meant. And then an idea struck me...

> I surmised that this had to be related to some physical property of the letters. And after staring at the screen a while I noticed that there was another connection to the theme here - the letters had been organised into categories based on the **number of 'peninsulas' in the letter**, with a 'peninsula' here being a 'loose end' on the outside of the letter. For example, the fully enclosed 'B' had no loose ends at all, 'Q' had just one at the bottom, and 'K' had a whopping four of them!
>
>  <sub>*Note from OP, added later: Technically, this puzzle involves counting something like "loose line segments" rather than "loose ends", as hinted by the key and the (unexpected) inclusion of the letter I in the '1' category of the grid, as remarked later in this answer:*</sub>
>
>  [image: Key, with loose line segments highlighted]
>
>  By this logic, it was possible to see that +=O and %=P, since an 'O' has no 'peninsulas' and a 'P' has one, putting them in categories '0' and '1', respectively.
>
>  [image: Step 4b]

**Step 5:**

Finally, time to fill the remaining spaces in the grid.

> Knowing the property governing the category definitions and that letters were ordered alphabetically, this was now a straightforward task:
>
>  [image: Step 5]
>
>  Note that this precise categorisation relies to some extent on the typeface used - for instance, the absence of a top bar on a 'J' (giving just two rather than three loose ends). The inclusion of 'I' in the '1' category is perhaps controversial - to my eye it has two loose ends, not just one, but never mind... The puzzle is now solved, and we have found our 'p of ps', or '**peninsula of peninsulas**' - a [nickname](https://education.nationalgeographic.org/resource/europe-human-geography) for the continent of **Europe**!

**Bonus:**

It's also worth pointing out that if you look at...

> ...a map of Europe, the clustered arrangements also somewhat resemble the shapes of these peninsulas and their relative positions on the map. Their arrangements have not been chosen at random!

Comment: Great solve! I did originally prefer I in the 2 row, but since it was a little ambiguous (no bend) went for 1 because it added an extra bonus - now the digits themselves are in the correct row!